# Как отправить значение enum на сервер?

Tags: java, spring-boot, enum

Команда состоит из 3 параметров: Integer id, time, channel (enum: abc/cba) param.

Param для abc: "abc:...";

Param для cba: "cba:...";

Сервер принимает команду и кладет в очередь указанным каналом.

Такое вот задание, не пойму поле channel должно принимать оба канала? или нужно для него 2-ое поле ввода (в html). И как передать значение enum, у меня вылетает 
ошибка :

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Enum'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The target type java.lang.Enum does not refer to an enum;
```

Конструктор

```
public Com(Integer id, String time, Enum<Params> param)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
        this.param = param;
    }
```

enum

```
public enum Params
{
    abc, cba;
}
```

Mapping

```
@PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam Integer id,
                      @RequestParam String time,
                      @RequestParam Enum<Params> params,
                      Model model)
    {
        Com com = new Com(id, time, params);
        comRepo.save(com);

        Iterable<Com> coms = comRepo.findAll();

        model.put("coms", coms);

        return "com";
    }
```

html

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id">
        <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="time">
        <input type="text" name="params" placeholder="channel">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Во-первых, попробуйте везде в качестве типа использовать не `Enum<Params>`, а `Params`, т.к. он и так уже enum.

Comment: Теперь не выдает ошибку, если ввести abc или cba, но при добавлении текста  (abc + "...." или cba + "...") вылетает ошибка

Comment: @JanJack а зачем нужен добавленный текст?

Comment: потому что каналов два abc и cba, но есть дополнительные параметры, где канал может иметь расширение и может быть abcde например или cbazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно принимать параметром String ,а затем использовать Params.valueOf() на нужной части строки.

```
    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam Integer id,
                      @RequestParam String time,
                      @RequestParam String param,
                      Model model)
    {
        Com com = new Com(id, time, Params.valueOf(param.substring(0,2));
        comRepo.save(com);

        Iterable<Com> coms = comRepo.findAll();

        model.put("coms", coms);

        return "com";
    }
```

Comment: спасиб, это нужное направление )